# How to make String variable hold value of 2 different arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

I would like the variable String name to hold 2 different index of an array.
EXAMPLE `name = anArray[1] anArray[2]`
Is this possible??

So when I invoke a print statement such as,

```
System.out.println("Element at index 0: " + name);
```

I would like the above statement to print the value in index 1 and index 2 of anArray

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] anArray;
    String name;

    // allocates memory for 10 integers
    anArray = new String[4];      
    // initialize first element
    anArray[0] = "mike";
    // initialize second element
    anArray[1] = "Rice";
    // and so forth
    anArray[2] ="John";
    anArray[3] = "Rice";

    name &= anArray[0] anArray[1];

    System.out.println("Element at index 0: "
                       + name);        
  }
 }
```

I am getting error that says:

> test.java:22: error: ';' expected name &= anArray[0] anArray[1];
>
> test.java:22: error: not a statement name &= anArray[0] anArray[1];
>
> 2 errors

Comment: _The variable String name to hold 2 different index of an array._ Its `name = anArray[0] + anArray[1];`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
String[] anArray;
String name;

// allocates memory for 10 integers
anArray = new String[4];      
// initialize first element
anArray[0] = "mike";
// initialize second element
anArray[1] = "Rice";
// and so forth
anArray[2] ="John";
anArray[3] = "Rice";

name = anArray[0]+","+ anArray[1];

System.out.println("Element at index 0: "
                   + name);
```

}
 }

Answer (score 6):

change `name &= anArray[0] anArray[1];` to `name = anArray[0] + anArray[1];`